# Center GridView vertically within LinearLayout

Tags: android

This is a popular question, but throughout my extensive searching on Stack Overflow, I couldn't quite seem to find a solution that actually did what I'm looking to do. This is my activity file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <GridView
      android:id="@+id/menu_options"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:numColumns="2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my individual grid item layout file (I generate the items dynamically via Adapter):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/menu_button"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      android:textSize="25sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And my result is this: [See image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDMoV.png)
[image]

I want those buttons to be smack dab in the middle of my view, can I do this through XML or do I have to manually calculate the dimensions and add padding (etc) by myself? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you wan to this 4 button at middle and line by line ?

Comment: @MohammadAli I want them vertically aligned as a group, so instead of having all that white space at the bottom, I want half of that to be above those buttons, and half to remain (so that they appear centered vertically).

Comment: i think in a Linerlayout u have to take a **`gravity:center`** or **`margin:top`**

Comment: in any layout you can use `gravity` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/menu_options"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Grid item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/menu_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is successfully centering them within their respective grid "cell"s if I can call them that, but not the actual GridView as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Use gravity center on Grid parent container and then wrap_content in you GridView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center"
          tools:context=".MainActivity">

          <GridView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/menu_options"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```